# Compute $\int_{\gamma} y dx$ where $\gamma$ is the curve shown.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-topology

I'm at a loss on what to do with the following question from a previous differential topology exam:

Let $\gamma \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be the curve shown below with self-intersecting points $(0,0), (2,1)$ and $(4,2)$:

[image: The curve gamma]

I'd imagine since this is in the context of differential topology, we are supposed to use Stoke's theorem, where we get:

$\int_{\gamma} ydx = \int_{R} dydx$
where $R$ is the region bounded by $\gamma$, but I am honestly having trouble doing the calculus on the right hand side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for a simply closed curve $\gamma=\partial R$ going around $R$ counterclockwise we have $$\int_\gamma y\>dx=-\int_R 1\> {\rm d}(x,y)=-{\rm area}(R)\ .$$ Split your $\gamma$ into a closed lower part $\gamma_1$ and a closed upper part $\gamma_2$ by choosing $(0,0)$ as dividing point. Then 
$$\int_\gamma y\>dx=\int_{\gamma_1} y\>dx+\int_{\gamma_2} y\>dx$$
is the area of the topmost part (above the $\infty$) of your figure minus the area of the lowest part (below the $\infty$), which is $=0$ if the figure is symmetric with respect to the line $(0,0)\vee(4,2)$.

Comment: Is the region bounded by top half of the figure eight the topmost part and the region bounded by the bottom half of the figure eight the bottom most part?